# I can't get my terminal to open folders or files with spaces in the title in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, files-folders

I've Googled but on how to type in folder or files with spaces but it doesn't seem work.

[image]

Comment: You sure you want your full name to be public in that screenshot. Also, I have tested it out with a `C Projects` directory on my MacBook Air and it works. Might be an extra space before or after the directory name.

Comment: Why not use autocomplete? `cd C` + Tab

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Gantendo I needed to add a / at the end of the file folder
for example `cd C\ Projects/`

Comment: The trailing slash is not necessary, it must have been something else that made it work.